# Drupal 9. Tiene alguna forma de crear tablas y/o relaciones (BD) o todo hay que hacerlo por modulos

Tags: drupal, drupal9

estoy aprendiendo drupal 9. Suelo usar paragraph para crear componentes, pero me preguntaba si quiero crear un form para que guarde, que se yo.., **las mascotas de los empleados**. Yo para hacer eso *pensaria ...* .

> Necesito una tabla **mascotas** y saber donde drupal guarda la tabla de **users** y crear una relacion **1-N (user-mascota)** ,etc...

Pero claro, aqui va todo por modulos, y no se muy bien de que forma se haria (por supuesto que me imagino q todo eso y mucho mas se puede hacer, pero al verlo tan **modularizado** en el sentido mas estricto de la palabra, me cuesta visionarlo. No obstante, sigo aprendiendolo y en algun momento aparecera este tipo de cosas, se que esta basado en **symfony** yo se **laravel** asi que imagino que no tendre una dificultad muy grande en entenderlo cuando lo vea, pero me gustaria visionarlo ya para ir con sobre aviso.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Drupal 9 no esta basado totalmente en Symfony, _algunos_ componentes se utilizan desde Drupal 8. En tu módulo deberás agregar la definición de la entidad (Entity) mascota, y no tendrías que tocar la base de datos, Drupal lo hará por ti.

Comment: @Sal De acuerdo, me cuesta entender eso pero te entiendo, ya que estoy acostumbrado a hacerlo manualmente ese tipo de operaciones, me imagino q con el tiempo entrare en razon jeje, muchas gracias !! =)